# Excess of array dimension in Fortran 90/95

Tags: fortran90

I am very curious about how printing of the 3rd row in the following is possible or at least why it is not a trash value:

```
PROGRAM b
    INTEGER:: A(2,2) = reshape((/1,2,3,4/),(/2,2/))

    PRINT*, A(1,:)
    PRINT*, A(2,:)
    PRINT*, A(3,:)  
END PROGRAM b
```

My result is:

```
       1           3
       2           4
       3       66825
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a trash value to me. set your compiler to do bounds checking to catch that

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reason why I said that it does not look like a trash to me is because in my other problem it has meaningful value.

Comment: What is the interest of interpreting something that you did you set, and you don't even know when/why it was set? Why do you define A to be 2x2 and try to read A(3,:) or A(4,:)?

Answer (score 0):

Your 66825 is a trash value! Even if you got just 0, it is still an undefined behavior that can cause bad result or crash your program (or even start WWIII). Do not do this. Use features provided by the compiler to check the array bounds and other similar stuff:

```
gfortran -fcheck=all

ifort -check
```

and so on.

You can also use valgrind on Linux to see undefined values and invalid reads and writes in memory.